# F# - компилятор под macOS

Tags: .net-core, f#

Существует ли компилятор для F# в виде отдельного бинарного файла, а не подключаемой при сборке библиотеки?

Здесь - `/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.102/FSharp` есть и fsc, и fsi - но они не являются исполняемыми файлами.

Env: macOS, .NET Core 2.2

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что они не являются исполняемыми файлами?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, простите за банальный ответ - потому что они не исполняются. При попытке выполнить fsc.exe получаю ошибку с описанием `cannot execute binary file`.

Comment: Их нужно исполнять через `dotnet` - вот так: `dotnet fsc.exe`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, спасибо! Может, вынесете в ответ?

Comment: Готово, вынес .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно, эти файлы не являются исполнимыми с точки зрения MacOS. Но их можно запустить на исполнение с помощью `dotnet`, вот так:

```
> dotnet fsc.exe
```